# Validating data on full row editing mode in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-grid, I want to organize a full row editing. I don't know how to catch errors, especially after an error on the backend side. Then I need to stop the save process. How will this be achieved?

in case of an exception, I want to stop further saving.but ag-grid saves data on grid